# How to put <li> content in the middle with before: and after: images?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to make a navigation using `<ul>`, I have two images (36px height) that are the right and left borders of a button (list item).

I add them with `before:` and `after:` in my css, but after I do that, the link inside the `<li>` (For example: "Main") appears in the bottom because of the two images I added (before: and after:).

I want the text to be in the middle of the two Images like a normal button.

[image: Example of error]

The green is what I want, the red is what I get.

Comment: How did you create the other two buttons? And do you have some code that we can have a look at? Otherwise its guessing how to solve the problem.

Comment: You can put a `vertical-align` on the `li::before` and `li::after`, but that works only if you know the line height and the height of the images. And if there's no other CSS that interferes...

Comment: please provide the code with css to see this issue

Comment: Why aren't you just using CSS backgrounds on your links themselves?

Comment: @Diodeus my guess is the OP wants the buttons stretchable.

Comment: http://css3button.net/ or http://css-tricks.com/examples/ButtonMaker/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for trying to help, but somehow I managed to do it.
This is the css:

```
#topmenu ul{
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
}

#topmenu ul li{
float: left;
margin-right: 5px;
background-image: url('images/btnback.png');
background-repeat: repeat-x;
height: 36px;
border-radius: 8px;
}

#topmenu ul li:before{
content: url('images/btnLeft.png');
float: left;
}

#topmenu ul li:after{
content: url('images/btnRight.png');
}
```

and this is the HTML:

```
<div id="topmenu">
<ul>
<li>
<a href="#">Main</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#">About</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#">Contact</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```